# remove certain vectors from a list

Tags: r

I want to remove certain vectors from a list. I have for example this:

```
a<-c(1,2,5)
b<-c(1,1,1)
c<-c(1,2,3,4)
d<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
exampleList<-list(a,b,c,d)

exampleList returns of course:
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 5

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there a way to remove certain vectors from a list in R. I want to remove all vectors in the list exampleList which contain both 1 and 5(so not only vectors which contain 1 or 5, but both). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Filter`:

```
filteredList <- Filter(function(v) !(1 %in% v & 5 %in% v), exampleList)
print(filteredList)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 1 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
```

`Filter` uses a functional style.  The first argument you pass is a function that returns `TRUE` for an element you want to *keep* in the list, and `FALSE` for an element you want to *remove* from the list.  The second argument is just the list itself.

Comment: One alternative is `Filter(function(x) length(setdiff(c(1,5), x)) > 0, exampleList)`.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `sapply` on every list element and remove those elements where both the values 1 and 5 are present.

```
exampleList[!sapply(exampleList, function(x) any(x == 1) & any(x == 5))]

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: or `exampleList[!sapply(exampleList, function(x) all(c(1,5) %in% x) )]`

Comment: @jogo yess and all this time I was trying with something like `x %in% c(1, 5)` which was definitely giving me incorrect results.

Comment: ... and I was searching for a one-step variant of my answer :D

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution with two steps:

```
exampleList<-list(a=c(1,2,5), b=c(1,1,1), c=c(1,2,3,4), d=c(1,2,3,4,5))
L <- lapply(exampleList, function(x) if (!all(c(1,5) %in% x)) x)
L[!sapply(L, is.null)]
# $b
# [1] 1 1 1
# 
# $c
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Here is a one-step variant without any definition of a new function

```
exampleList[!apply(sapply(exampleList, '%in%', x=c(1,5)), 2, all)]
```

(... but it has two calls to apply-functions)